# New to git and keep getting the error when I make a new repository via Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I keep getting this error when I make a new repository:

> Failed to parse config file: Invalid configuration key (in
>   /Users/username/.gitconfig:3, column 0) (-1)

In terminal:

```
git init
```

> fatal: bad config line 3

in file /Users/username/.gitconfig line 3 is my email line and is accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the configuration file, in terminal write:

```
git config --global user.email example@email.io
```

And just in case update also the username:

```
git config --global user.name "yourUserName"
```